# Search Many2many field

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

`employee_idv01` is a `many2many` field and `employee` is a `Many2one` field

```html
records_shift = self.env['shift_affectation'].search([('employee_idv01','=',employee.name),('date_r2','>=',date1),('date_r1','<=',date2),])
```

How Can I do my search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code:

```
records_shift =self.env['shift_affectation'].search([('employee_idv01','=',self.employee.id),('date_r2','>=',self.date1),('date_r1','<=',self.date2)])
```

Comment: you can remove (,)  in last in your domain

Comment: Error:                                                                                                           records_shift = self.env['shift_affectation'].search([('employee_idv01','=',self.employee_id.id),('date_r2','>=',date1),('date_r1','<=',date2),])
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/api.py", line 752, in __getitem__

Comment: employee_idv01 is a M2m field, so it s not logical to use a = .

Comment: try this code records_shift =self.env['shift_affectation'].search([('employee_idv01','=',self.employee.id),('date_r2','>=',self.date1),('date_r1','<=',self.date2)])

Comment: unfortunately an Error again :    records_shift = self.env['shift_affectation'].search([('employee_idv01','=',self.employee_id.id),('date_r2','>=',date1),('date_r1','<=',date2)])
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/api.py", line 752, in __getitem__

Comment: Great Man, Thanx for the help.